# kubectl : unable to recognize "csr.yaml": no matches for kind "CertificateSigningRequest" in version "certificates.k8s.io/v1"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, certificate-signing-request

i have this template i try to invoke: looking at the docs example [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/)

```
--- 
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata: 
  name: vault-csr
spec: 
  groups: 
    - system: authenticated
  request: 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
  signerName: kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving
  usages:
  - digital signature
  - key encipherment
  - server auth
```

the version of kubectl:

```
$ kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.20.0
Server Version: v1.18.9-eks-d1db3c
```

And im working with AWS EKS
i keep getting :

```
$ kubectl create -f csr.yaml
error: unable to recognize "csr.yaml": no matches for kind "CertificateSigningRequest" in version "certificates.k8s.io/v1"
```

**UPDATE**
after changing to apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1

```
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata: 
  name: vault-csr
spec: 
  groups: 
    - system: authenticated
  request: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURSB.....
  usages:
  - digital signature
  - key encipherment
  - server auth
```

Im getting now this error:

```
$ kubectl create -f csr.yaml
error: error validating "tmp/csr.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(CertificateSigningRequest.spec.groups[0]): invalid type for io.k8s.api.certificates.v1beta1.CertificateSigningRequestSpec.groups: got "map", expected "string"; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [K8s change doc](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.19.md#api-change-5), the `CertificateSigningRequest` API is promoted to `certificates.k8s.io/v1` only as part of the K8s `1.19` release.

It was under `certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1` before that.

I suspect that to be a problem as your server version is `v1.18`.

So, try changing your `apiVersion` as below:

`apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1`

Comment: Thanks for the answer please see my updated question after  changing I'm still getting error

Comment: found the problem! this is sick its should be : - system:authenticated
and not - system: authenticated   ( see the space)